# homebrew not recognizing proper xcode version on Mojave

Tags: xcode, macos, homebrew, graphviz, macos-mojave

When I run: `brew install graphviz`

I see this error:

```
Error: Your Xcode (1) is too outdated.
Please update to Xcode 8.3.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from
  https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Error: Your Command Line Tools are too outdated.
Update them from Software Update in the App Store.
```

My system is:

```
OS-X 10.14.1 Mojave
```

To determine the xcode version I ran `pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables`

giving the output:

```
package-id: com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
version: 10.1.0.0.1.1539992718
volume: /
location: /
install-time: 1544538474
groups: com.apple.FindSystemFiles.pkg-group
```

It appears that my xcode version is 10.1.

Also when I run `brew doctor`

I see this output:

```
Warning: Your Command Line Tools are too outdated.
Update them from Software Update in the App Store.


Warning: Anaconda is known to frequently break Homebrew builds, including Vim and
MacVim, due to bundling many duplicates of system and Homebrew-available
tools.

If you encounter a build failure please temporarily remove Anaconda
from your $PATH and attempt the build again prior to reporting the
failure to us. Thanks!
Error: Unrecognized Mach-O load command: 0x32
```

I am pretty suspicious of the `Macho-0` error. I am not sure what that is. Pleae comment if you need more information.

`brew -v`

yields

```
Homebrew 1.1.12-38-g30582a5
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision fa840; last commit 2018-12-11)
```

Comment: Did you try to update `brew` (current version is 1.8.4)? Also, what is `xcode-select -p` reporting?

Comment: I agree. I would do exactly what the error message suggests. Make sure xcode-select points at the correct Xcode, and download and install the current command line tools for Xcode.

Comment: Hello guys, 
I am facing error while running "brew install ios-deploy" command. Any solution?